# Analysis of residuals from generalized linear model with binomial family

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals

I have fit a *GLM* where the response variable represents ratio and used *Binomial* family. Below is my model

```
library(foreign)
df <- read.dta("http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/401k.dta")
df$prate <- df$prate/100

myglm <- glm(prate ~ mrate + age + sole, data = df, family = binomial)
summary(myglm)
```

Now I want to get *quantile residuals* of above fit. As per the discussion in the paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2647151_Randomized_Quantile_Residuals, in order to estimate *quantile residuals*, I need to convert the response variable to *standard normal variable*.

However, given that in my case I only have ratios (not actual realization of binomial distribution), I could not figure out how exactly I should estimate the *quantile residuals* in this case.

Is there any direct or approximate method available to obtain such residuals for this type of model fit?

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: Use the DHARMa package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compute randomized quantile residuals without the binomial numbers.
In fact you cannot fit a binomial glm corrrectly without them either.

But the dataset you have loaded does include the binomial realizations.
You need:

```
library(foreign)
df <- read.dta("http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/401k.dta")
df$prate <- df$totpart / df$totelg
myglm <- glm(prate ~ mrate + age + sole, data = df, family = binomial, weights = totalelg)
library(statmod)
qr <- qresid(myglm)
```